# How can I tell which AD-group is giving a specific user access to a folder?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Given a user ID and a folder, how can I tell which of the groups is the reason that the user has which access?

Comment: use case?  If you dont want them to access the folder, add a deny for them.  If you do want them accessing the folder, well... they already can.  Is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: In this case, I was trying to work out which of the roles applied to a folder was the one being used to give me access, so I could then request the same role for a team-mate.
I ended up using a combination of Get-Acl and an ActiveDirectory lookup script to grab all of my groups and do an SLS against the existing roles.
(I'd never want an individual getting access to a location on a person-by-person basis.  Everything should be through groups.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Powershell script I just knocked up which gets you most of the way there.  It gives you all of the ACLs on a file/folder which match the roles a user is in:

```
Param($fileName,$user)

$groups = ([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($user)").Findone().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'
$acls = (get-acl $fileName).access
$aclNames = $acls.identityreference.Value
#sls returns match objects, we need strings
$aclsForUser = $aclNames | sls $groups | %{$_.tostring()}
$acls | ? IdentityReference -in $aclsForUser
```

Answer (score 1):

Go the property-security of the folder to check which group has the access right the folder, the add the user to the group via AD.

Comment: The user already has access.  I'd like to know which of the groups is granting which access to them.

So if there are 17 groups on the folder, which of them is granting the user RO access, which is granting RW access, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps:

1. Open Windows Explorer, and then locate the file or folder for which you want to view effective permissions.
2. Right-click the file or folder, click Properties, and then click the Security tab.
3. Click Advanced, click the Effective Permissions tab, and then click Select.
4. In Enter the object name to select (examples), enter the name of a user or group, and then click OK. The selected check boxes indicate the effective permissions of the user or group for that file or folder.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771586.aspx

Comment: So I'd need to manually find all of the groups the user is in, and then match them against each of the groups which have rights to that folder?

There's no automatic way of finding out which role that that user is in is giving the access?

Comment: It's a simple enough matter to determine the users group membership. One way is to access the properties of the user account in ADUC and look at the `Member Of` tab.

Comment: That's still a manual process to compare hundreds of user roles against a load of folder ACLs.  I was hoping for a nice simple command (or short script) to get folder ACLs, user AD groups, and compare one against the other.  I ended up writing my own.

Comment: Welcome to group sprawl...it would be nice if there was a attribute for a group that would allow you to enter freeform text to describe what the group is used for.